# Close sub menu when clicking another sub menu item

Tags: jquery

Hello i have this code to control the menu, it works great, but i would also want all other sub menus to close when i click to open some other sub menu.
In short: Klick one + to open a submenu, klick another + to open this sub menu and to close the first sub menu.

Thank you.

And it looks like i have to add some more details but i don't know what else to say.

```
/*
Flaunt.js v1.0.0
by Todd Motto: http://www.toddmotto.com
Latest version: https://github.com/toddmotto/flaunt-js

Copyright 2013 Todd Motto
Licensed under the MIT license
http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php

Flaunt JS, stylish responsive navigations with nested click to reveal.
*/
;(function($) {

// DOM ready
$(function() {

// Add some classes and Append the mobile icon nav
$('.nav').append($('<div class="nav-mobile"></div>'));
$('.nav > ul').addClass('nav-list');
$('.nav > ul > li').addClass('nav-item');
$('.nav > ul > li > ul').addClass('nav-submenu');
$('.nav > ul > li > ul > li').addClass('nav-submenu-item');

// Add a <span> to every .nav-item that has a <ul> inside. And add an sub menu icon indicator.
$('.nav-item').has('ul').prepend('<span class="nav-click"><i></i></span>');

// Click to reveal the mobile menu
$('.nav-mobile').click(function(){
$('.nav-list').toggle();
$('.nav-submenu').hide(); // This will close the submenu when i click the top ribbon (.nav-mobile) to close the mobile menu
if(!$('.nav-list').is(':visible')){ // the menu was closed because it's not visible anymore
$('.nav-item .nav-click').each(function(){ // loop through nav clicks
if($(this).hasClass('icon-close')) { // This will toggle back the + icon on mobile menu close/open
$(this).toggleClass('icon-close');           
}
}); 
}
});

// Dynamic binding to on 'click' and Toggle the nested nav
$('.nav-list').on('click', '.nav-click', function(){
$(this).siblings('.nav-submenu').toggle();

// This will toggle the + and - when clicked
$(this).removeClass('nav-click');
$(this).toggleClass('icon-close');
$(this).toggleClass('nav-click');   
});

// This will toggle the menu/submenu/- when click outside of the menu
$('.wrapper').click(function(event) {
$('html').one('click',function() {
$('.nav-list').hide();
$('.nav-submenu').hide(); // This will close the submenu when you click the top ribbon (hamburger button) to close the mobile menu
if(!$('.nav-list').is(':visible')){ // the menu was closed because it's not visible anymore
$('.nav-item .nav-click').each(function(){ // loop through nav clicks
if($(this).hasClass('icon-close')) { // This will toggle the +/- icon on mobile menu close/open
$(this).toggleClass('icon-close');
}
}); 
}
});
event.stopPropagation();
});

}); 

})(jQuery);
```

[Live demo](http://test3.fcab.se/responsive_menu_test/simple_multi_responsive_menu_flat/index.html)
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b1913dLq/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There may be a better way of doing it, but I think have got it to work the way you want it to.

http://jsfiddle.net/L73dqxhd/

Starting at line 40, I changed it to this:

```
// Dynamic binding to on 'click' and Toggle the nested nav
$('.nav-list').on('click', '.nav-click', function(){
    var currentSubmenu = $(this).siblings('.nav-submenu');
    var currentNavClick = $(this);
    $('.nav-submenu').not(currentSubmenu).slideUp();
    $('.nav-click').not(currentNavClick).removeClass('icon-close');
    $(this).siblings('.nav-submenu').toggle();
```

FWIW I would really recommend using something like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) for this as opposed to rolling your own.

It covers all sorts of bases and makes all kinds of things, like this, so much easier...

Comment: Thank you for your help. Now it works the way i want it to :)